# How do I make a (keyPressed) KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keylistener, java-2d

Im trying to write a very simple program that allows you to control a sprite with arrow keys and move around the screen. From what I understand, to do this I need a `keyPressed()` `KeyListener`. I believe Im doing this correctly based on the Java Doc but its not returning the correct output when I press the designated key. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code, and if possible, provide a simple example of the usage of this class? Thanks!

(Note, code is unfinished)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Display() {

        // super();
        loadImages();
        initTimer();
        this.addKeyListener(this);

    }

    BufferedImage sprite;
    Timer timer;
    int up = 0;

    public void loadImages() {
        File spriteImage = new File("Pacman_sprite.png");
        try {
            sprite = ImageIO.read(spriteImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Sprite import failed");
        }
    }

    public void initTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(100, this);
        timer.start();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println("Key press registered"); //does not print this?
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            System.out.println("sucess"); // does not print this?
            up++;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        System.out.println("release");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(sprite, 500, 500 + up, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    repaint();
}
```

}

**EDIT:**
May have found the answer here. I moved the key handling code to a new class called KeyHandler then added these two lines to the constructor:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
setFocusable(true);
```

It now appears to be working just fine (sort of, at least it is detecting when the up key is hit. My graphics aren't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the listener to the `JPanel`.

**Note:** I would suggest you to change your design. Right now, `Display` class is both a `JPanel` and a `Listener` (which doesn't make sense in my opinion).

But to add the listener in your code do something like,

```
this.addKeyListener(this); // This looks awkward right. That's why you should change the design.
```

in your constructor.

Comment: Okay, I am flexible with the design, In fact, originally I wrote the key listener in its own class called KeyHandler, but for simplitys sake I put it in Display. I also thought it might help solve my problem. Thanks for the answer, Ill give it a try. Unfourtunently I may have to go soon but Ill be back later today to keep trying with this stuff.

Comment: Quick question: Where do I add this line of code? Constructor?

Comment: @AshwinGupta, yes. Add it somewhere in the constructor. Preferably below `initTimer()`.

Comment: I would debug it by putting the print statement outside before the `if` condition and also print the `e.getKeyCode()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really helped actually. I did exactly what you said and I added the setFocusable(true) method call. Im accepting your answer, also if you want just so other people with this question can see it, you can add the setFocusable thing to your answer too.