# Java- KeyEvent method doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

I am making a sort of pong game, but I have a problem.
I have a method in my code, that checks if the user input is a key pressed.
But it won't execute when I press(In my case) the UP key.

This is the code, sorry for bad English, please help me:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
    Player player = new Player();
    Ball ball = new Ball();

    public GamePanel(){
        Timer time = new Timer(50, this);
        time.start();
    }

    private void update(){
        player.update();
        ball.update();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        player.paint(g);
        ball.paint(g);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        update();
        repaint();
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            player.setyv(-5);
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32046652/2775450), You have the same problem in your code as well.

Comment: @toskv: has nothing to do with that and much to do with KeyListener's requiring focus, and the JPanel not being naturally focusable nor focused. Better to use Key Bindings.

Comment: Yep. :) KeyEvent is in java.awt.event, so it's certainly not missing.

Comment: And don't forget to call the super.paintComponent(g)` method within your override.

Comment: I forgot to add it to the keylistener im sorry please do not dislike

Answer (score 1):

Again,

1. Use Key Bindings and not a KeyListener since this can help you take focus out of the picture without use of kludges.
2. Always be sure to call the super's paintComponent method within your override.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    Player player = new Player();
    Ball ball = new Ball();

    public GamePanel() {
        Timer time = new Timer(50, this);
        time.start();

        // !! set key bindings
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        KeyStroke up = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);
        inputMap.put(up, up.toString());
        actionMap.put(up.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                player.setyv(-5);
            }
        });

        KeyStroke down = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0);
        inputMap.put(down, down.toString());
        actionMap.put(down.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                player.setyv(5);
            }
        });
    }

    private void update() {
        player.update();
        ball.update();
    }

    // !! public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // !!
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H); // !!
        player.paint(g);
        ball.paint(g);
    }

    // !!
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
        repaint();
    }

    // !!
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GamePanel mainPanel = new GamePanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GamePanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

interface Playable {
    void update();

    void paint(Graphics g);
}

class Player implements Playable {
    private static final Color PLAYER_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Font FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 24);
    private int x = 400;
    private int y = 400;
    private int yv = 0;
    private int xv = 0;

    @Override
    public void update() {
        y += yv;
        x += xv;
    }

    public void setyv(int i) {
        yv += i;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(FONT);
        g.setColor(PLAYER_COLOR);
        g.drawString("P", x, y);
    }

}

class Ball implements Playable {

    @Override
    public void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I did not understand much of your code... The code I sent was from a class, the main class and stuff were in other files... I fixed it and it works, so why not use keylistener?

Comment: @HugoCornel: add a JButton to your program, something that can steal the focus and find out -- your KeyListener will stop working in this situation, forcing you to create unnatural kludges, like not allowing buttons to gain focus.

Comment: Why should I use buttons in a pong game I only needed a working respond to user input(key up in this case)

Comment: @HugoCornel: you've got a simple animation GUI right now, but in a real world application, you're likely going to have the animation surrounded by components that would allow the user to control the animation. Use of the primitive KeyListener will not work well in this situation. But suit yourself. I only posted this as an example of how to use Key Bindings with your own code. What you do with this example is up to you. I also recommend that you Google and read the Key Binding tutorial, since the knowledge gained can only help you.